# How to set MaxRetry value in msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth authentication Providers

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

Is there way to set  ***MaxRetry*** value when we use ***msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth*** as authentication Providers. I could see it  has set to 1 in *AuthenticationProviderOption* class

```
public class AuthenticationProviderOption : IAuthenticationProviderOption
{
        internal int MaxRetry { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Graph.Auth/ConfidentialClient/ClientCredentialProvider.cs#L97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the MaxRetry Property maximum value of 10 (retries). By default it will be 3 if you wont set anything.

Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.graph.retryhandleroption.maxretry?view=graph-core-dotnet)

```
requestMessage.GetRequestContext().MiddlewareOptions.Add(
typeof(RetryHandlerOption).ToString(),
new RetryHandlerOption()
{
MaxRetry = 3
});
```

Please do refer the [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-auth/blob/523d0853cc8bfbd222d7163d5dfd7ff8c41509b0/src/Microsoft.Graph.Auth/MsalAuthenticationBase.cs#L31) regarding how to set the MaxRetry property.

Comment: Thanks .Links are helpful. how do i set this value. can i set this when initializing Auth provider such as  "new ClientCredentialProvider(clientApplication) .SetMaxRetry(5)"

Comment: Hi @InfoÁsith I have updated the answer please refer